# Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'chart' while building via aot in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 4 application. I have recently introduced aot. When I do a normal build , the application builds fine but fails when I do a aot build.

I am getting the following error message

```
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'chart'. ("<chart [ERROR ->][options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>"): ng:///C:/Development/Risk.Analytics.Captives/Clientside/captives/src/app/shared/Highcharts/box-plot-chart/box-plot-chart.component.ts.BoxPlotChartComponent.html@0:7
'chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

I have created a shared module that is imported in app.module and pdf.module. I have the highchart components to the shared module as they are used by pdf and app module. However the chartmodule is declared in both app and pdf module

shared module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolkitModule } from '@wtw/toolkit';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AllComponentsModule } from '@wtw/platform/components';
import { BoxPlotChartComponent } from './shared/Highcharts/box-plot-chart/box-plot-chart.component';
import { HistogramChartComponent } from './shared/Highcharts/histogram/histogram-chart.component';
import { SplineChartComponent } from './shared/Highcharts/spline/spline-chart.component';
import { DynamicFieldComponent } from './shared/dynamic-field/dynamic-field.component';
import { IndustrySelectionComponent } from './shared/industry-selection/industry-selection.component';
import { EsriMapComponent } from './shared/esri-map/esri-map.component';
import { NetPresentValueAnalysisProjectionComponent } from './pages/feasibility/results/net-present-value-analysis/projection/net-present-value-analysis-projection.component';
import { ProjectionTableComponent } from './pages/feasibility/results/projection-table/projection-table.component';

export const SHARED_COMPONENTS = [
    BoxPlotChartComponent,
    SplineChartComponent,
    HistogramChartComponent,    
    DynamicFieldComponent,
    IndustrySelectionComponent,
    EsriMapComponent,
    NetPresentValueAnalysisProjectionComponent,
    ProjectionTableComponent
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AllComponentsModule,
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule,
        ToolkitModule
    ],
    declarations: SHARED_COMPONENTS,
    exports: SHARED_COMPONENTS
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

app.module

```
    import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
      import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
      import { SharedModule, SHARED_COMPONENTS } from './shared.module';

      const ROOT_COMPONENTS = [
      ...PLATFORM_COMPONENTS,
      ...SCORECARD_COMPONENTS,
      CaptivesComponent,
      DomicileSelectionComponent,
      AssumptionsComponent,
      ...LINES_COMPONENTS,
      ...RESULTS_COMPONENTS

    ];

    export function highchartsFactory() {
  const hc = require('highcharts');
  const hb = require('highcharts-histogram-bellcurve');
  const dd = require('highcharts/modules/drilldown');
  const hcMore = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  const exp = require('highcharts/modules/exporting');
  hcMore(hc);
  hb(hc);
  dd(hc);
  exp(hc);
  return hc;
}

declare var require: any;
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [...ROOT_COMPONENTS ],
          imports: [

             ChartModule, SharedModule 
          ],
          providers: [...WEBAPI_PROVIDERS, ...SERVICES, {
                provide: HighchartsStatic,
                useFactory: highchartsFactory
            }],
          bootstrap: [PlatformRootComponent],
          entryComponents: [...SHARED_COMPONENTS, ...ROOT_COMPONENTS]
        })
        export class AppModule { }
```

pdf module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
import * as  BackendProxy from './api/proxies';

import { PdfRootModule } from '@wtw/platform/pdf';
import { PdfPage } from './pdf/pdf.component';
import { PdfDomicilePage } from './pdf/pdf.domiciles.component';
import { PdfResultsPage } from './pdf/pdf.results.component';
import { PdfResultsPageHeader } from './pdf/pdf.results.page-header/pdf.results.page-header.component';
import { PdfResultsPageFooter } from './pdf/pdf.results.page-footer/pdf.results.page-footer.component';
import { PdfResultsContents }  from './pdf/pdf.results.contents/pdf.results.contents.component';
import { PdfResultsStrategy }  from './pdf/pdf.results.strategy/pdf.results.strategy.component';
import { PdfResultsStrategyHeader }  from './pdf/pdf.results.strategy-header/pdf.results.strategy-header.component';




import { WEBAPI_PROVIDERS } from './api/proxies';

import { ScorecardService, StrategyService, PdfDataService } from './services';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';

export function highchartsFactory() {
  const hc = require('highcharts');
  const hb = require('highcharts-histogram-bellcurve');
  const dd = require('highcharts/modules/drilldown');
  const hcMore = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  hcMore(hc);
  hb(hc);
  dd(hc);
  return hc;
}

declare var require: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PdfPage, PdfDomicilePage, PdfResultsPage,
    PdfResultsPageHeader, PdfResultsPageFooter, PdfResultsContents,
    PdfResultsStrategy, PdfResultsStrategyHeader],
  imports: [
    PdfRootModule, ChartModule , SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [...WEBAPI_PROVIDERS,
    { provide: HighchartsStatic, useFactory: highchartsFactory },
    BackendProxy.ScorecardProxy, StrategyService,
    BackendProxy.ReferenceProxy, ScorecardService, PdfDataService
    ],
  bootstrap: [PdfPage],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class PdfModule { }
```

box plot component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ShortNumberFormatPipe } from '@wtw/toolkit';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-box-plot-chart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
        chart{
              display: block;
              width: 95% !important;
              padding:0;
        }
    `]
})

//, width: number
export class BoxPlotChartComponent implements OnInit {
    static chart(shortNumberFormatPipe: ShortNumberFormatPipe, translate: TranslateService, moduleName: string, height: number, width: number, marginTop: number,  graphLegendTitle: string) {
        return {
            chart: {
                type: 'boxplot',
                reflow: true,
                height: height,
                width: width,
                marginTop: marginTop
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
             chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        allowHTML: true,
                        enabled: true,
                        margin: 25,
                        itemMarginTop: 0,
                        symbolRadius: 0,
                        symbolHeight: 20,
                        symbolWidth: 20,
                        useHTML: true,
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                           title: {
                            text: '',
                         }
                    },
                    chart: {
                              height: 500,
                              xAxis: {},
                              events: null }
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {

                lineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                minorTickLength: 0,
                tickLength: 0
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: false,
                useHTML: true,

                formatter: function() {
                    let isMillionNumber: boolean = false;
                    const row = function(label, value) {
                        const key = 'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.';

                        return '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">' + translate.instant(key + label) + ': </td>'
                            + '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>' + value + '</b></td></tr>';
                    };

                    const transformNumber = function(value) {
                        isMillionNumber = validateMillionNumber(value);
                        if (isMillionNumber || moduleName === 'eva')
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 2);
                        else
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 0);
                    };

                    const table = function(format, point) {
                        let txt = '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:' + point.color + '">' + point.series.name + '</strong><br><br>';
                        txt += '<table>';
                        if (moduleName === 'npv') {
                            txt += row('HIGH', format(point.high));
                            txt += row('Q3', format(point.q3));
                            txt += row('MEDIAN', format(point.median));
                            txt += row('Q1', format(point.q1));
                            txt += row('LOW', format(point.low));
                        } else if (moduleName === 'eva') {
                            txt += row('HIGH', format(point.high) + '%');
                            txt += row('Q3', format(point.q3) + '%');
                            txt += row('MEDIAN', format(point.median) + '%');
                            txt += row('Q1', format(point.q1) + '%');
                            txt += row('LOW', format(point.low) + '%');
                        }
                        txt += '</table>';
                        return txt;
                    };

                    let point = this.point;

                    return table(transformNumber, point);

                    function validateMillionNumber(millionNumber: number) {
                        return millionNumber >= 1000000;
                    }
               },
            },
            series: []
        };
    }

    public options: any;
    chart: any;
    @Input() public series: any;
    @Input() public moduleName: string = '';
    @Input() public height: number = 400;
    @Input() public width: number;
    @Input() public marginTop: number;

    private shortNumberFormatPipe = new ShortNumberFormatPipe();

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadChart();
    }

    loadChart() {
         let graphLegendTitle: string = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.GRAPH_LEGEND_TITLE');
        this.options = BoxPlotChartComponent.chart(this.shortNumberFormatPipe, this._translate, this.moduleName, this.height, this.width, this.marginTop, graphLegendTitle);
    }

    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }


    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;
        data.series.currentValue.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });
        this.loadChart();
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;
        this._redrawLogic(this.series);
        this.chart.redraw();
    }

    private _redrawLogic(series: any) {
        let seriesLength = this.chart.series.length;
        for (let i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            this.chart.series[i].remove();
        }

        series.map(s => {
            if (s !== null) {
                this.chart.addSeries(s);
            }
        });

        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item path');
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-height', '20');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give "forRoot" a try, to make sure all dependent modules are included with ChartModule:

```
  ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')
```

(As seen in the doc example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts)

While you're at it, module "forRoot" imports are worth understanding when managing multiple modules:
https://medium.com/@chrishouse/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7

(If both modules need the ChartModule, you may want to move it to the SharedModule?)